how can i set state of amp-list and submit the form with that state
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡4email data-css-strict>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-list" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-list-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.2.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
    <style amp4email-boilerplate>
        body {
            visibility: hidden
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <amp-state id="selectedProduct">
        <script type="application/json">
            {
                "src": "imageSrc",
                "title": "ProductName",
                "price": "400"
            }
        </script>
    </amp-state>

    <div class="container">
        <amp-list width="500" height="500" layout="responsive" src="https://bounce.mailamp.in/similar-products" items="products">
            <template type="amp-mustache">
                <div class="product-item" on="tap:AMP.setState({
                        selectedProduct: {
                            src: {{src}},
                            title: {{title}},
                            price: {{price}}
                        }
                    })">
                    <amp-img class="product-image" width="100" height="100" src="{{src}}" alt="Product Image"></amp-img>
                    <p>{{title}}</p>
                    <p>Price: ₹{{price}}</p>
                    <form method="post" action-xhr="https://bounce.mailamp.in/add-to-cart">
                        <input type="hidden" name="src" [value]="selectedProduct.src">
                        <input type="hidden" name="title" [value]="selectedProduct.title">
                        <input type="hidden" name="price" [value]="selectedProduct.price">
                        <button type="submit" class="add-to-cart-button">Add to Cart</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </template>
        </amp-list>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

I'm working on an AMP for Email project and trying to implement an interactive product list using amp-list and amp-state. However, I'm facing issues with updating the state when a product is clicked. Below is the code snippet I'm using. I would appreciate any guidance on how to properly set this up for dynamic user interactions.
Specifically, I am unsure if I am using the AMP.setState correctly to update the selectedProduct state when a product is tapped. Any insights or corrections would be greatly appreciated!

It would be helpful if you can provide a sample HTML with an XHR endpoint that works for others to help debug. When I paste the provided sample in the playground, I'm getting an AMP CORS error: Request xhr failed: The amp-access-control-allow-source-origin must be equal to the amp source origin sent in the request.​​​.

That's another problem i can't seem to make a request from the amp playground even though i added their endpoints but it works when i make a request from the gmail. But the problem i am facing is that the state doesn't change when click on div or button. If you want i can send you the data i am receiving in amp-list

I tried the sample you provided in your question in Gmail too. I got this error: Access to fetch at 'https://bounce.mailamp.in/similar-products' from source origin 'amp@gmail.dev' has been blocked by AMP CORS policy: The 'AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin' header has a value 'rishab@mailamp.in' that is not equal to the supplied source origin.​​​ So it doesn't work in Gmail either. In order to help debug, we'll need a working XHR endpoint first that responds the correct JSON state.

It looks like you are hardcoding the value of the AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin header to rishab@mailamp.in in your endpoint. It would help if you can modify your server to instead respond with a value of the Amp-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin header in the request so that it works for whoever needs to help debug from the playground or Gmail (with origin amp@gmail.dev).

res.setHeader('AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin', [
'rishab@mailamp.in',
'amp@gmail.com',
'https://playground.amp.dev',
]);
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.status(200).json(response);
i am doing this i added the playground url but still can't make request from playground. Do you know how can i add it to work from playground. I am sorry but an I am new to amp-email. Also thank you for responding

I am using [link] (playground.amp.dev/?runtime=amp4email) this playground. I also tested it with incognito and other users it's working. Although i am not seeing anything on googles playground but the xhr request is successful. I also adding the screenshot to the request. [link] (https://imgur.com/gallery/vlMDj0u)

I sorry to bombard you with you so many questions but can you tell me how can i show the amp-list like horizontally? I want to show products as rows. I tried adding display flex but it doesn't work.

Re: res.setHeader('AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin', [ 'rishab@mailamp.in', 'amp@gmail.com', 'playground.amp.dev', ]); - I don't think you can set multiple values for that header. You can use a wildcard * or an individual value echoing the value of the __amp_source_origin query parameter (AMP CORS V1). I just realized that I incorrectly said to "instead respond with a value of the Amp-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin header in the request" - I should've said "instead respond with a value of the __amp_source_origin query parameter in the request".

The reason why your XHR works in the AMP playground (playground.amp.dev/?runtime=amp4email) is that the AMP playground doesn't perform the proper AMP CORS checks. When you productionize your emails you still need to fix the AMP CORS issues I mentioned above or else it won't work in Gmail. The XHR still fails for me in the Gmail playground (https://amp.gmail.dev/) because the Gmail playground does do AMP CORS checks. For your other question about layout you should post a new question.

There are a few orthogonal problems with the sample you provided:
1. You are missing quotes in the JSON returned by your endpoint.
Here's what the on attribute on the <div> looks like after the Mustache template is rendered:
tap:AMP.setState({
    selectedProduct: {
        src: https://bummer.in/cdn/shop/files/9000000664.2561_600x.jpg?v=1708346823,
        title: Trunks - Disco82,
        price: 599.00 
    } 
})

This results in an error when you click on the div to trigger AMP's execution of the setState call:
Error: Parse error on line 3:
...          src: https://bummer.in/cdn/sho
-----------------------^
Expecting '-', '+', '*', '/', '%', '&&', '||', '<=', '<', '>=', '>', '!=', '==', '?', '.', ',', '[', '}', got ':'

You should see these errors in the JS console.
The values for src and title need to be quoted if the values are string literals. See examples at https://amp.dev/documentation/components/email/amp-bind#deep-merge-with-amp.setstate().
2. There's no order dependency between the setState call and the form submission
When you click on "Add to Cart", the form submission doesn't wait for the amp-bind evaluation on the hidden form input elements to execute after the state changes when the outer div is clicked. They happen in parallel in undefined order. As a result, what typically happens is that the first time you click on "Add To Cart", the form submits with the input fields set to the default values of the AMP state (src: imageSrc and price: 400) you set inside the <amp-state> tag, as opposed to the values you intend to set using AMP.setState.
What you can do is to ensure that the form is only submitted after the setState happens. This can be done by

Giving your form a DOM ID
Changing the button to a regular button and not a submit button
Chaining multiple actions upon the same event and use form.submit action to trigger the form submission:

https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/email/learn/amp-actions-and-events#multiple-actions-for-one-event
If you give your <form> element a DOM ID of form, then you can do this:
<button on="tap:AMP.setState({
              selectedProduct: {
                src: '{{src}}',
                title: '{{title}}',
                price: '{{price}}',
              }
            }), form.submit" type="button" class="add-to-cart-button">
  Add to Cart
</button>

You can debug AMP states by executing AMP.printState() in the JS console, in the context of the AMP frame.
3. Your form endpoint has CORS issues
Even after fixing the above issues, your form submission doesn't work because it doesn't respond with the correct CORS headers:
Access to fetch at 'https://bounce.mailamp.in/add-to-cart?__amp_source_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fplayground.amp.dev' from origin 'https://playground.amp.dev' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.


Thank you so much, You have helped a lot. I made the changes you told me and I added the credentials: true so the xhr request is working in the playground, but when i submit the form, in Payload Form Data of the request tab i only see src and price, I don't see the title but when i give input some different "name" property like productName it is showing in the Form Data.  Also the amp-list is not rendering on (https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/) even though the get request is successful.

The name="title" attribute on the form input element is likely sanitized away by DOMPurify, which is used by amp-mustache. DOMPurify tries to prevent DOM clobbering. In this case, title is a banned symbol because it's a native attribute on some built-in JS object, e.g., document.title. In this case the name attribute can't clobber document, but DOMPurify tries to be conservative and sanitize even when it's not strictly necessary.

Re: "Also the amp-list is not rendering on (amp.gmail.dev/playground) even though the get request is successful" - see my notes under the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/78357161/1397618. You will need to fix the AMP CORS issues I mentioned. The GET XHR is failing in the Gmail playground.

Thank you so much for the help. I added this in the backend const ampSourceOrigin = req.query.__amp_source_origin;  res.set('AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin', ampSourceOrigin); and it works now. But when i make form post xhr from (playground.amp.dev/?runtime=amp4email) i am getting undefined but i am getting log from (amp.gmail.dev/playground) Also I added a new question about the amp-list layout if you would be kind enough to look at it: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78370357/how-can-i-show-amp-list-horizontally-when-i-style-the-container-as-display-fle)

I tried the sample again in the AMP playground (playground.amp.dev/?runtime=amp4email) and it works for me. It also works in the Gmail playground now. Not sure where you saw "undefined".

Oh sorry for that unclear comment, I am getting undefined on backend server when make the post request "add-to-cart" from (https://playground.amp.dev/?runtime=amp4email), but when i make the same request from (https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/) i am getting the log of productName, price and src.

The AMP playground uses multipart/form-data while the Gmail playground uses application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Make sure your server can handle both interchangeably.
