How can I show amp-list horizontally? When i style the container as display: flex i can't see the list at all
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡4email data-css-strict>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-list" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-list-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.2.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
    <style amp4email-boilerplate>
        body {
            visibility: hidden
        }
      
      
    </style>
  
  <style amp-custom>
    .container {
      display: flex;
      
    }
    .product-item {
      width: 200px;
      
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <amp-state id="selectedProduct">
        <script type="application/json">
            {
                "src": "",
                "productName": "",
                "price": ""
            }
        </script>
    </amp-state>

    <div class="container">
        <amp-list width="500" height="500" layout="responsive" src="https://bounce.mailamp.in/similar-products"
            items="products">
            <template type="amp-mustache">
                <div class="product-item">
                    <amp-img class="product-image" width="100" height="100" src="{{src}}" alt="Product Image"></amp-img>
                    <p>{{title}}</p>
                    <p>Price: ₹{{price}}</p>
                    <form id="form" method="post" action-xhr="https://bounce.mailamp.in/add-to-cart">
                        <input type="hidden" name="src" [value]="selectedProduct.src">
                        <input type="hidden" name="productName" [value]="selectedProduct.productName">
                        <input type="hidden" name="price" [value]="selectedProduct.price">
                        <button on="tap:AMP.setState({
                            selectedProduct: {
                              src: '{{src}}',
                              productName: '{{title}}',
                              price: {{price}},
                            }
                          }), form.submit" type="button" class="add-to-cart-button">
                            Add to Cart
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </template>
        </amp-list>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

I'm working on an AMP for Email project and trying to implement an interactive product list using amp-list and amp-state. However, I am facing issues with styling the amp-list. I want to show the amp-list horizontally but when i add container style as display: flex I don't see the amp-list at all.

use a responsive table: https://codepen.io/lukepeters/pen/JjoVWd
